# Android background service stalls after running for sometime

Tags: android, json, service, sms-gateway

I have written an SMS Gateway application which would intercept an incoming message through a broadcast receiver and store it into the custom SQLite database using a content provider, this part works very well and it has never failed.

In the same application i have created a service which schedules a TimerTask to run every 10 seconds to look for the stored messages and forward them to the web application url using json, then retrive reply messages generated by the web app and send them to reciepients using SmsManager.

The timer task is started using onStart() method like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){

    updateNotification("Ready...");

    if(mTimer != null){
        mTimer.cancel();
    }else{
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule the the timer task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new JanjaTask(), 0, 1000*RECURSIVE_TIMER_SECONDS);

}
```

and the timer task is written like this:

```
private class JanjaTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                List<JanjaMessage> messages = mDB.getAllPendingMessages();       

                if(!messages.isEmpty()){
                    Log.d("Janja Service:", "Processing Local pending messages..."); 
                    for (JanjaMessage msg : messages) {
                        sendJson(msg.getSender(), msg.getMessage(), msg.getTimestamp(), msg.getID());
                    }
                }else{                  
                    if(REPLY_ONLINE_MESSAGES){
                        Log.d("Janja Service:", "Processing Online pending messages...");
                        sendJson("replicator", "checking for pending message", "", 0);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }

}
```

the code used to start the service is written like this:

```
Intent janjaIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), JsonRemoteService.class);
startService(janjaIntent);
```

**Problem**
This is starts fine when application main UI is launched and when the device boots it will work as expected for sometime maybe 20 - 30 minutes then stall all the messages sent to the phone will not be forwarded to the server until the phone reboots or you explicitly kill the service from the running services list then messages are getting replied

In android 2.x phones when you go to **Settings > Applications > Running services** you find it is listed there with words 1 process and 1 service under its name, it can stay running as other services like facebook and whatsapp without responding as desired until i stop it from there or reboot the phone.

I will really appreciate for your help on this issue

**NOTE**
I have tried to resolve the issue using Alarms and IntentService but the app would end up crashing. Any suggestion please.